# specific line error php

Tags: php, mysqli

```
 global $db_name;
      echo '<p><h3>Your Shopping Cart</h3></p>';

      if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {

        $total = 0;
        echo '<table>';
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th>Code</th>';
        echo '<th>Name</th>';
        echo '<th>Quantity</th>';
        echo '<th>Cost</th>';
        echo '</tr>';
        foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $product_id => $quantity) {
///the problem is with these two line underneath 
//Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\.... on line 147
        $do= "SELECT product_code, product_name, product_desc, qty, price FROM products WHERE id = .$product_id";
        $result = mysqli_query($db_name,$do);


        if($result){

          while($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
            $cost = $obj->price * $quantity; //work out the line cost
            $total = $total + $cost; //add to the total cost

            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$obj->product_code.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$obj->product_name.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$quantity.'&nbsp;<a class="button [secondary success alert]" style="padding:5px;" href="update-cart.php?action=add&id='.$product_id.'">+</a>&nbsp;<a class="button alert" style="padding:5px;" href="update-cart.php?action=remove&id='.$product_id.'">-</a></td>';
            echo '<td>'.$cost.'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
          }
        }

      }



      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td colspan="3" align="right">Total</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$total.'</td>';
      echo '</tr>';

      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td colspan="4" align="right"><a href="update-cart.php?action=empty" class="button alert">Empty Cart</a>&nbsp;<a href="products.php" class="button [secondary success alert]">Continue Shopping</a>';
      if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        echo '<a href="orders-update.php"><button style="float:right;">COD</button></a>';
      }

      else {
        echo '<a href="login.php"><button style="float:right;">Login</button></a>';
      }

      echo '</td>';

      echo '</tr>';
      echo '</table>';
    }
```

there is a line where it states

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs.... on line 147

I just cant figure out what to do there watched a lot of tuts but non helped. i would be obliged if any of you could help me figure out what the problem is there.

Comment: [documentation with working example](http://php.net/mysqli_query) - you cannot just feed it `$db_name` which is the *string* name of your database.  you must create an instance of `mysqli` like this: `$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");`.  Again, [the documentation has a simple example that will work for you](http://php.net/mysqli_query)

Comment: Your next error will be becaue `.$product_id` is not concatenating, you are already in quotes..Either close the encapsulation or just throw it in. This also is open to SQL injections.

Comment: Check the connection object. Otherwise show us the `database connection`. You can put dummy values while posting.

Comment: i have that before this code :

Comment: Show it, but remove credentials...

Comment: $currency = '$';
$db_username = 'root';
$db_password = '';
$db_name = 'ecommerce';
$db_host = 'localhost';
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password,$db_name);

global $db_name;

Comment: See `$mysqli` is your connection, not `$db_name`. Also try to stay object oriented or procedural.

Comment: thanks bro you helped me out it works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is coming from here

```
$result = mysqli_query($db_name,$do);
```

As you are passing in the *name of the database*.

The function [`mysqli_query`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp) has two requeired parameters:

```
mysqli_query( connection, query );
```

The connection, is the connection the query will be executed, without it, the method has no idea what to do with your query.

Taken from one of your comments:

```
$db_username = 'root';
$db_password = '';
$db_name = 'ecommerce';
$db_host = 'localhost';

$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password,$db_name);
```

You need to now use

```
$result = mysqli_query( $mysqli , $do );
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the variable `$db_name`. I can't see in your code where it comes from, but it has to be of type `mysqli`.

According to the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-parameters), the first argument needs to be **"A link identifier returned by mysqli_connect() or mysqli_init()"**

So you have to create a `mysqli` object with one of these functions and then pass that object to `mysqli_query()`.

And a side note: You should use prepared statements. Otherwise it's way too easy to produce insecure code.

Comment: $currency = '$';
$db_username = 'root';
$db_password = '';
$db_name = 'ecommerce';
$db_host = 'localhost';
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password,$db_name);

global $db_name;